# Join two queries become one subquery

Tags: t-sql, subquery

I want to ask how to combine these two queries become one subquery?

```
select c.CustomerName, A.Qty
from Customer c join (select s.CustomerID, pd.Date, s.Qty
     from Period pd join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID) A on c.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
where @Date = A.Date
```

and

```
select sum(case when (pd.Date between '2010-03-15' and @Date) then s.Qty else 0 end) as TotalQty
from Period pd full join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID full join Customer c on s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
group by c.CustomerName, c.CustomerID
```

They should result one table contains these following columns: CustomerName, Qty, and TotalQty. I've tried many ways but they didn't work at all. Really hope your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question assuming you are looking at the result as one row and not "column" :

```
select c.CustomerName, A.Qty,(select sum(case when (pd.Date between '2010-03-15' and @Date) then s.Qty else 0 end) 
                from Period pd full join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID full join Customer c on s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                group by c.CustomerName, c.CustomerID
                 ) as TotalQty
from Customer c join (select s.CustomerID, pd.Date, s.Qty
     from Period pd join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID) A on c.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
where @Date = A.Date
```

If you still want the result as a single column , google "row to column transpose"

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo earlier, but I've edited my question. By the way, your answer works for me but it brings some other problems up. Thanks anyway for your solution. :)